# How to install apk with minimum number of clicks?

Tags: android, installation, apk

There are rumors that you can put apk on your server, then send someone link to this apk via SMS and with single click the apk will be installed. Without root and without Google Play.

I know only this way:
1. Click one the link. 
2. Click on Accept to start download. 
3. Click on downloaded apk file. 
4. If installing from "Unknown sources" is disabled you need to click Settings then scroll down and enable this checkbox. Then again press OK. 
5. Press Install to accept permissions.

Do you know faster way to install apk?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do you know faster way to install apk?

The behaviors of Steps 1-3 are determined by the client app. Different client apps will behave differently. Some might have fewer steps. Some might have more.

Step 4 may or may not happen, depending on the device's setup, as you note.

Step 5 will always exist, though whether it lists any permissions depends upon whether the app requests any.

Hence, if you want a "faster way to install apk", choose a better client app. For example, last I checked, Dropbox's client would effectively remove Steps 2 and 3, as you would just click on the APK file in the Dropbox app (roughly equivalent to Step 1).